# Counting backwards from end date in pd.Grouper

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to aggregate daily data to weekly (7-day sum) but with the last date as the 'origin'. Is it possible to do a group by from the end date using pd.Grouper? This is how the data looks like:

[image]

This code:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='7d'))['value'].sum()
```

results to

```
2020-01-01     5
2020-01-08    12
2020-01-15     4
```

but I was hoping for this:

```
2020-01-01 0 
2020-01-03 7
2020-01-10 14
```

Comment: Could you add some example input and your wanted output?

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica I made edits thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the method you have used can be shortened using `resample` method of pandas on df

but i think you problem is the order your dates are;

the result you expect is more day wise output;

hence what i will recommend is splitting the df and then again merging them

```
df.set_index(['date'],inplace=True)
df_below = df[3:].resample('W').sum()
```

```
df_up = df.iloc[0:3,:].sum()

# or you can give dates instead of 0:3 in  iloc
```

the rows [0,1,2] you can take sum of those n then using `hstack or concat or merge` again make them one DataFrame

feel free for asking further queries....